# Problems executing useEffect in a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, jwt

I'm building an application in React and I'm having some problems, I want to change some styles of a component that was created with Material UI, Paper, this style should be changed when TYPE_USER is equal to 0, for this I created two useEffect, one to receive and save the data, the other to do the verification and change the styles, this is the code

```
function SideBarLeft() {
  const style = useStyles();
  
  const [disableSearch, setDisableSearch] = useState(false);
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState('Funcionário ou NIF');
  const [funcao, setFuncao] = useState('');
  const [nome, setNome] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    const id = decoded.user.ID;
    console.log('id: ' + id)
    
    axios
        .get(`${API_BASE_URL}/user/${id}`) 
        .then((res) => {
          setFuncao(res.data.user.TIPO_UTILIZADOR);
          setNome(res.data.user.NOME_UTILIZADOR);
        
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
    );
  } , []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if ( funcao === 0  ) {
      console.log('funcao: ' + funcao)
      setDisableSearch(true);
      setPlaceholder(nome);
    } else {
      setDisableSearch(false);
      setPlaceholder('Funcionário ou NIF');
    }
  }, [ funcao, nome]);
  }, []);
```

This is the code from the Paper where I want to change the styles:

```
return (
  <div className={style.sideBarSearch}>
    <Paper component="form" className={disableSearch ? style.sideBarSearchPaperFuncionario : style.sideBarSearchPaper} >
      <InputBase
        className={style.sideBarSearchInput}
        sx={{ ml: 1, flex: 1, input: {
          color: 'white',
          "&::placeholder": {
            opacity: 1,
           },
         }, }}
         placeholder={placeholder}
         readOnly={disableSearch}
         inputProps={{ style: { color: disableSearch ? '#FFFFFF' : 'black' }}}
        />
        {disableSearch ? null : <SearchIcon sx={{ p: '10px', color: '#0093FF'}} />
        }
    </Paper>
  </div>
```

I've tried a few times, mainly with console.log to check if after the if `( funcao == 0 )`, it was being executed, but no, even though the data was being set correctly

Comment: if `res.data.user.TIPO_UTILIZADOR` is a string '0' instead of number 0, your logic might not work. Could you check the value of `funcao` and `nome`? `useEffect(() => { console.log('funcao: ' + funcao); console.log('nome: ' + nome); }, [ funcao, nome]);`.

Comment: I tested a console.log before the `if` and it returned the values I expected, but the second console.log returned nothing, this was the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log ('funcao: ' + funcao, 'nome: ' + nome)
    if ( funcao === 0  ) {
      console.log('funcao: ' + funcao)
      setDisableSearch(true);
      setPlaceholder(nome);
    } else {
      setDisableSearch(false);
      setPlaceholder('Funcionário ou NIF');
    }
  }, [ funcao, nome]);
```

Comment: If the first log prints out expected values, there's error in your condition `if ( funcao === 0 ) `. When you say 'returned nothing', did the second `console.log` execute and print out `funcao: `? or it did not execute at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need second useEffect? Maybe move logic from it to `axios.then`?

```
axios
        .get(`${API_BASE_URL}/user/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {
            const tipo = res.data.user.TIPO_UTILIZADOR
            const nome = res.data.user.NOME_UTILIZADOR

            if (tipo === '0') {
                setDisableSearch(true)
                setPlaceholder(nome)
            } else {
                setDisableSearch(false)
                setPlaceholder('Funcionário ou NIF')
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

Comment: I created a second useEffect to prevent when the page is reloaded the values from becoming null

Comment: I don't know what happened, but for some reason with that code it is already working perfectly, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the approach you took may be not required, like nesting useEffects() just to change styles.

As far as I have understood, you can change the styles dynamically in react. You can use `sx={ state ? {style1} : {style2}}` inside the mui component i.e conditionally render your styles. The styles will be applied automatically when the state is changed. I hope you don't need two nested useEffect hook.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the styles because the second useEffect is not even executed